# How can I add a Stack Exchange login to my preexisting account?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, stack-exchange-openid

When I created my account, I used Facebook Connect as my only login type and I can only log in to my account using it.

I wish to create a Stack Exchange login to be able to log in with instead of Facebook Connect, but I can't find how to do this.
It seems that the option for creating a Stack Exchange login is only present when creating a new account?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**My initial answer was wrong, so I did some research and I *think* I have a solution for you.**

First of all, you're not crazy. It is really hard to add a Stack Exchange login to a preexisting account -- the option isn't currently included on the 'My Logins' page. We're looking at some better solutions, but for now, I have a kludgy work around for you:

1. First, make sure you're logged in to your account. Then, go to
   the [account recovery
   page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) and put
   in the same email address which is tied to your current non-Stack
   Exchange login.
2. Go to your inbox and open up the email you
   should have just received from our system. The very last line of the
   email should say

> "If you'd like to use xyxyxyx@hotmail.com to log in,
>           click here to set a new password."

3. Click through and add a password to associate with your email address.
4. Head back to your account, go to 'Edit Profile & Settings' --> 'My logins' and check to see if an SE OpenID is now one of the options.
5. **Success!** (*hopefully...)*

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I had a Google login on my account. The account recovery option didn't work as it insisted there was no such e-mail in the system. However when I created an account on stackexchange using the e-mail from my Google account (using [this form](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register)) - I could use it to log into my existing account. Confusing, but at least it worked!

Comment: Following allowed me to add a new email as Stack Exchange login in april 2022: I was logged in with my former email. At first I added the email in account settings and verified it. Secondly I logged out and tried to log in using this new email. SE rejected my login attempt. Then I clicked on password recovery link in the login form, received a recovery email and followed instructions. Now this email is not listed in "Other" category any more. It is in "Stack Exchange" category.